# Setting a greeting based on user's time (Good morning, good afternoon…)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Can anyone extrapolate on how to implement a basic "good evening" or "good morning" based on the user's time setting?

Perhaps PHP will fetch the server time, but I'm looking to greet the site visitor with a time-based appropriate greeting that considers their time of day.

**E.G.:** good morning, good night, good afternoon.

Answer (score 36):

Base it on `.getHours()` of the date object. Using javascript's Date object will automatically use the user's local time, rather than the server-time:

```
var now = new Date();
alert( now.getHours() );
```

A couple conditional checks, and you're in business. For instance, the following is a very simple and easy-to-understand example:

```
var now = new Date();
var hrs = now.getHours();
var msg = "";

if (hrs >  0) msg = "Mornin' Sunshine!"; // REALLY early
if (hrs >  6) msg = "Good morning";      // After 6am
if (hrs > 12) msg = "Good afternoon";    // After 12pm
if (hrs > 17) msg = "Good evening";      // After 5pm
if (hrs > 22) msg = "Go to bed!";        // After 10pm

alert(msg);
```

It's currently 2:56am here, so I see "Mornin' Sunshine!" when I run this. You can test your own local time with this online demo: http://jsbin.com/aguyo3/edit

Comment: Remember to have a fallback in case the time could not be detected or when Javascript is disabled, e.g. preset `msg = 'Welcome'`.

Comment: when javascript is disabled, you don't need `msg = 'Welcome'` cause there is no javascript

Comment: @Gordon: Correct. This example is by no means suppose to be anything more than an example.

Comment: Also, I'd use a switch/case for this to be able to break after the first condition is met. No reason to check if hrs is e.g. greater 12 when it is not greater than 6. But good example nonetheless.

Comment: @Natrium when the time could not be detected **or** when Javascript is disabled. In the latter case, you'd have to write Welcome somewhere else, presumabely as default innerHTML in a span reserved for greetings.

Comment: Mmmmm, cheesecakepie.

Answer (score 20):

```
<?php
// I'm India so my timezone is Asia/Calcutta
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');

// 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros (0 through 23)
$Hour = date('G');

if ( $Hour >= 5 && $Hour <= 11 ) {
    echo "Good Morning";
} else if ( $Hour >= 12 && $Hour <= 18 ) {
    echo "Good Afternoon";
} else if ( $Hour >= 19 || $Hour <= 4 ) {
    echo "Good Evening";
}
?>
```

For more information about date see [function.date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). I Hope this will help.

Comment: You might want to check that last criteria - can `date('G')` be 19 or more _and_ 4 or less at the same time? :D

Comment: The last criteria is ok, its checking if date('G') is bigger or equal to 19 **OR (thats the  double | )** less or equal to 4, its not using AND (&&)

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
    /* This sets the $time variable to the current hour in the 24 hour clock format */
    $time = date("H");
    /* Set the $timezone variable to become the current timezone */
    $timezone = date("e");
    /* If the time is less than 1200 hours, show good morning */
    if ($time < "12") {
        echo "Good morning";
    } else
    /* If the time is grater than or equal to 1200 hours, but less than 1700 hours, so good afternoon */
    if ($time >= "12" && $time < "17") {
        echo "Good afternoon";
    } else
    /* Should the time be between or equal to 1700 and 1900 hours, show good evening */
    if ($time >= "17" && $time < "19") {
        echo "Good evening";
    } else
    /* Finally, show good night if the time is greater than or equal to 1900 hours */
    if ($time >= "19") {
        echo "Good night";
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$hour      = date('H');

if ($hour >= 20) {
    $greetings = "Good Night";
} elseif ($hour > 17) {
   $greetings = "Good Evening";
} elseif ($hour > 11) {
    $greetings = "Good Afternoon";
} elseif ($hour < 12) {
   $greetings = "Good Morning";
}
echo $greetings;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const now = new Date().getHours();

switch (true) {
    case (now<=12): console.log("Good Morning");break;
    case (now>12 && now<16): console.log("Good Afternnon");break;
    case (now>=16 && now<20): console.log("Good Evening");break;
    case (now>=20 && now<=24): console.log("Good Night");break;}
```

This code is based on JavaScript, Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function greeting_msg() {
    $hour = date('H');
    if ($hour >= 18) {
       $greeting = "Good Evening";
    } elseif ($hour >= 12) {
        $greeting = "Good Afternoon";
    } elseif ($hour < 12) {
       $greeting = "Good Morning";
    }
    return $greeting;
}
```