# Timed Based Events for Website

Tags: jquery, actionscript, time

I was wondering if it was possible to make a small script in Jquery that would change an image at a certain time.

For my site, I want the image for the opening and closing of a facility to change when it opens and closes.

Is this possible with Jquery or should I go with something else? Actionscript/Flash? I can't use PHP on the site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need JQuery, although that has code that will help. You just need to test the `Date` object and go from there. For example, code like this changes a greeting based on time of day -- no reason why you can't tweak that to do what you need:

[Stackoverflow: Setting a greeting based on user's time (Good morning, good afternoon…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182511/setting-a-greeting-based-on-users-time-good-morning-good-afternoon)

EDIT: I ought to have made it clear that as one might expect, `Date` works with the date / time on the **client** machine.

Comment: That seems to be just what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

you create function callback that loads a new image from an array of image links

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use a function such as `getTimeZoneOffset()`, you can get the local time in GMT, add the offset for the actual location of the facility, then you base all of your calculations of GMT time, then regardless of where you site is looked at, it will show the correct status.